# Array Map callback function with only one argument returns the callback function argument as index instead of the item itself

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I don't know why this is happening but in an array where i am running the `map` function, the callback function of maps get its first argument as the index number instead of the item. If I assign two arguments then it's working like how it should work i.e first arg as index and second arg as item but when i assign only one argument it gives me index number instead of the item itself.

Below is my function block:

```
return companies_det.map(function (company_det) {
     console.log(company_det);
     var $ = cheerio.load(company_det);
     var company_name = $(company_det).find('a').text(),
         company_esomar_url = $(company_det).find('a').attr('href');

     return Rq(company_esomar_url)
            .then(function (web_data) {
                  var $ = cheerio.load(web_data);

                  return {
                          company_name: company_name,
                          company_url: $('a[data-ga-category="website"]').attr('href')
                        }
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                       return err;
                  })
             });
```

In the above function, If I do `console.log(company_det)` I receive `index number` instead of the `companies_det` array items.

Comment: could you post a working jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible if companies_det is an Array of objects and map is Array.map.
You have not provided the code with the actual problem.  Either you stored the array indices in companies_det, or companies_det is not an array and it is not the standard map function.

Try logging companies_det.

Comment: `companies_det` is an object array returned by Cheerio